# TFS - Not Retrieving Nuget packages for a referenced project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a folder structure that looks like this

```
Customer.Common
Customer.Data
Customer.WebPortal
Customer.ConsoleApp
```

The Common and Data projects are shared across multiple Visual Studio solutions. They were not added to the solutions by using the 'Shared Projects' feature, they were just adding by doing 'Add existing project' if that makes a difference

```
Customer.WebPortal
    Customer.Common
    Customer.Web
    Customer.Data


Customer.ConsoleApp
    Customer.ConsoleApp.
    Customer.Data
    Customer.Common
```

TFS is not retrieving the Nuget packages for the Customer.Common Project. so it won't build.

Customer.Data project builds fine but that's only because the WebPortal project also has the same nuget dependencies.

TFS is 2015, developers are using a mix of VS2013 and VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

When you are building your Customer.WebPortal, MSBuild will run this command: `nuget.exe restore  xxx\Customer.WebPortal.sln`  . So this step is for sln level, it won't restore your customer.Common project.

There are two ways for your situation  :

- Add the nuget dependencies of Customer.Common to Customer.WebPortal 
     (Simple and effective)
- Build the three projects instead of build the whole solution (In this
  case, MSBuild will run `nuget.exe restore xxx\xx.csproj`)